# Calculate $D^3f $ if $ f(x,y)= e^x cos(y)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

I want to know if my answer is correct, please.

Let $f(x,y)=e^x cos(y)$, calculate $D^3f$.

Solution:

We have that $Df = [\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \space \space \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}]$, then:

\begin{equation}
Df=
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{x}cos(y) & -e^{x}sin(y) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
D^2f=D(Df)=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y} \\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{x}cos(y) & -e^{x}sin(y) \\
-e^{x}sin(y) & -e^{x}cos(y) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

And finally:

\begin{equation}
D^3f=D(D(Df))=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_3}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial f_4}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_4}{\partial y} \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{x}cos(y) & -e^{x}sin(y) \\
-e^{x}sin(y) & -e^{x}cos(y) \\
-e^{x}sin(y) & -e^{x}cos(y) \\
-e^{x}cos(y) & e^{x}sin(y) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Therefore,

\begin{equation}
D^3f=
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{x}cos(y) & -e^{x}sin(y) \\
-e^{x}sin(y) & -e^{x}cos(y) \\
-e^{x}sin(y) & -e^{x}cos(y) \\
-e^{x}cos(y) & e^{x}sin(y) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: Yeah I think this looks good

Comment: @CalabiYau, thank you!